# Sql time points to time range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following sql table:

```
id   time
1    2018-12-30
1    2018-12-31
1    2018-01-03
2    2018-12-15
2    2018-12-30
```

I want to make a query which will result in following data:

```
id  start_time end_time
1   2018-12-30 2018-12-31
1   2018-12-31 2018-01-03
2   2018-12-15 2018-12-30
```

Is this even possible to do with sql in reasonable amount of time or it is better to do this with other means?

Failed approach (it takes too much time):

```
SELECT id, time as start_time, (
    SELECT MIN(time)
    FROM table as T2
    WHERE T2.id = T1.id
    AND T2.time < T1.time
) as end_time
FROM table as T1
```

I have dates in my db, each of them have non unique id. I want to calculate time range between closest dates for each id. So transformation should be performed on each id separately and should not affect other ids. We can even forget about ids, and just imagine that I have only one column in my DB which is dates. I want to sort my dates and perform sliding window with step 1 and capacity 2. So if I have 10 dates, I want to have in a result 9 time ranges, which are should be in increasing order. Assume we have four dates: D1 < D2 < D3 < D4. Result should be (D1,D2), (D2,D3), (D3,D4)

Comment: Yes, it's pretty simple in MySQL 8.x, but cumbersome in MySQL 5.x. Which one do you have?

Comment: It is helpful if you were to explain the exact rules to go from start to finish.

Comment: @Hogan I have dates in my db, each of them have non unique id. I want to calculate time range between closest dates for each id. So transformation should be performed on each id separately and should not affect other ids. We can even forget about ids, and just imagine that I have only one column in my DB which is dates. I want to sort my dates and perform sliding window with step 1 and capacity 2. So if I have 10 dates, I want to have in a result 9 time ranges, which are should be in increasing order. Assume we have four dates: D1 < D2 < D3 < D4. Result should be (D1,D2), (D2,D3), (D3,D4)

Comment: I think you want to partition by ID and then apply D1 < D2 < D3 < D4 => (D1,D2), (D2,D3), (D3,D4)

Comment: @Hogan Is it any different to what `The Impaler` answer describes? And if yes, is there any performance win?

Comment: No I think @TheImpaler is right on the money.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL 8.x you can use the `LEAD()` function to peek at the next row:

```
with x as (
  select
    id,
    time as start_time,
    lead(time) over(partition by id order by time) as end_time
  from my_table
)
select * from x where end_time is not null
```

Comment: Looks like LEAD is available for me, I will check how it performs and will write you back :)